# how exclude parent element and sub element nodes

Tags: xml, marklogic

How to exclude "Approach"" and "Amount1" elements. I can exclude "Amount1" but unable to get both nodes(Approach,Amount1) eliminate.

Sample.xml:

```
<root>
  <Approach> Approach </Approach>
  <Progress> Progress </Progress>
  <Objective> Objective </Objective>
  <fundingSources>
     <Source>
         <Amounts>
             <Amount1>thousands</Amount1>      
             <Amount2>millions</Amount2> 
        </Amounts>
    </Source>
  </fundingSources>
</root>
```

I can remove a Amount1 node by doing this fn:doc("sample.xml")//*[not((descendant-or-self::Amount1))]

result return:

```
<root>
  <Approach> Approach </Approach>
  <Progress> Progress </Progress>
  <Objective> Objective </Objective>
  <fundingSources>
     <Source>
         <Amounts>
             <Amount2>millions</Amount2> 
        </Amounts>
    </Source>
  </fundingSources>
</root>
```

But struggle to combine another parent node name "Approach" to omit.  Thanks.

Comment: You can try this:  ```doc('sample.xml')//*[not(descendant-or-self::Approach | descendant-or-self::Amount1)]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive approach. XSLT would work well for this, but you can do it with XQuery like this too:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:filter(
  $nodes as node()*
)
  as node()*
{
  for $node in $nodes
  return typeswitch ($node)
    case element(Approach) return ()
    case element(Amount1) return ()
    case element()
    return element { node-name($node) } {
      $node/@*,
      local:filter($node/node())
    }
    case document-node()
    return document {
      local:filter($node/node())
    }
    default return $node
};

let $xml := <root>
  <Approach> Approach </Approach>
  <Progress> Progress </Progress>
  <Objective> Objective </Objective>
  <fundingSources>
     <Source>
         <Amounts>
             <Amount1>thousands</Amount1>      
             <Amount2>millions</Amount2> 
        </Amounts>
    </Source>
  </fundingSources>
</root>
return
  local:filter($xml)
```

HTH!